# unable to run my first application in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am just getting started with flutter... I am using `VS Code Editor`.I located the `SDK` and when I run `main.dart` file it throws me this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on HUAWEI Y560 U02 in debug mode...
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\...\flutter\flutter_first\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details


> Configure project :app

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\...\Android\sdk\licenses

Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in C:\...\Android\sdk\licenses

Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* Where:

Build file 'C:\...\flutter\flutter_first\android\build.gradle' line: 24


* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

   > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
        platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
        build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
     Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

     Using Android SDK: C:\...\Android\sdk


* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 6m 14s
  Command: C:\...\flutter_first\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Exited (sigterm)
```

What should I do now? any help please! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and check with

```
flutter doctor -v
```

that there are no remaining serious issues.

Comment: still not working it is like this `Exception: Android sdkmanager tool not found (C:\...l\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,`

Comment: Can't tell from here. Perhaps only some path setting is missing, but if it prints the path `C:\...l\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager` then the path is set but not to the correct directory or as the message says the Android SDK installation is incomplete or corrupted.